# How do I show my argspec/docstring in bpython?

Tags: python, bpython

I'm just starting to use bpython, mainly because I really think it will help the office nubs a lot. In bpython, it continually shows help text as you type. For example

```
>>> zip(
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ zip: (seq1 [, seq2 [...]])                                             │
│ zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]            │
│                                                                        │
│ Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element    │
│ from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated   │
│ in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.             │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This is great for the less educated (and even novice's like myself). However nothing shows up for my custom built functions. I thought maybe it was just displaying the docstring so I added docstrings to my functions. Nothing changed. Can someone explain to me what it is showing here and how I add it to my functions?

EDIT: 
It must be some weird inheritance issue. This is being done with Django's custom managers.

```
class PublicationManager(models.Manager):
    """blarg"""
    def funct(arg):
        """foo"""
        pass

class Publication(models.Model):
    objects = PublicationManager()
```

Typing `PublicationManager.funct(` shows the docstring but `Publication.objects.funct(` does not. I guess the nubs will have to figure it out for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your documentation string as the first line of your function:

```
def funct():
    "This function is self-documenting"
    pass
```

Use triple quotes if it spans multiple lines:

```
def funct():
    """
     This function doesn't expect arguments
     and returns zero.
    """
    return 0
```

To get at the help in the repl use help():

```
>>> help(funct)
```

Or to programmatically get at the docstring, use `__doc__`:

```
>>> print funct.__doc__
This function doesn't expect arguments
and returns zero.
>>>
```

Comment: It looks like he already tried that ("I thought maybe it was just displaying the docstring so I added docstrings to my functions. Nothing changed.").

Comment: @Bastien @yan Yeah I was stupid and didn't try the super simple case. Sorry. I explained the issue further. I don't think it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add it after your function line:

```
def myFunc():
    """You Doc String Here
    (even multiline)"""
    pass
```

It's same for the classes:

```
class MyClass():
    """Class Documentation"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Function Documentation"""
        pass
```

But for modules, you write docs at the top of the file:

```
#File: mymodule.py
"""Module Documentation"""

class Classes()...
def functions()...
```

Now if you import that in your main file:

```
import mymodule.py
print mymodule.__doc__
```

Comment: 'fraid that's not even python. Also the docstrings go inside of the def, not above it.

Comment: OK Thanks i was in the atmosphere of doxigen :) i corrected it.

Comment: Should be def instead of function